# Change subtitle of app - Is my app available on the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, subtitle

I just got my app on the App Store I think - I'm not so sure because I don't have an iPhone and I can't check but I think it is available on iTunes [here](http://itunes.apple.com/mk/app/school-class-reminder/id1334870219?mt=8). I didn't add subtitle on the app version and now I get my name - "Viktor Kuzmanov" as a subtitle. I created new version of the app and as subtitle.

I created another version of the app in iTunes.

My questions are :

- Do I need to submit the app again and go through the process to just change the subtitle ?
- I am not sure is iTunes and App Store the same ?

**Disclaimer**: I don't ask this question for promoting the app and if anything is wrong I will delete the link.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, to make changes to the title or subtitle of the app you need to submit a new version.
- iTunes connect is where you submit app to the play store. Once you submit an app and its approved you can release it and it will appear in the App Store

Comment: And If I submit new version now I will not write anything in "What's new" so will the app appear in App Store with no text or it would not appear ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can change the "What's new" section even after you submit and release

Comment: I tried not writing anything in "What's new" and it didn't allow me to submit for review so I just wrote "- bug fixes" in it so I can submit the app